# Want to use atoi() on type char whilst reading a file?

Tags: c++

I have extracted the contents of a file mapped into memory, into an array which looks like:

```
char* const arr = static_cast<char *>(file.get_address());
```

whilst iterating through the array I wish to be able to call:

```
for(int i=0; i<file.get_size(); i++){
    atoi(arr[i]);
}
```

however, atoi requires type const char* and arr[i] is type char* const. How may I resolve this?

Comment: What is the issue you are actually experiencing? in C or C++ you can always pass a non-const X into a function expecting a const X; it is the other way round which is prohibited.

Comment: @JesusPlusPlus Better use [snprintf()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/) to avoid buffer overflows. I think that this is also the wrong direction - atoi() converts `string to integer`.

Comment: apart from my initial pondering of why you're not using `std::strtol()`, you're passing a **char** into your atoi() call, which clearly isn't right, if you're doing `atoi(arr[i])`. I think you meant `atoi(arr+i)`.

Comment: Since it's tagged as `C++`, why not convert using a `stream` object (`std::stringstream` for instance), or with `boost::lexical_cast`?

Comment: You might also want to take a peek at `boost::lexical_cast` to see if it would be helpful.

Comment: @JesusPlusPlus I think this is one situation where everyone will agree with me to *not do what Jesus does*. `atoi` returns an integer from its string representation. How exactly would you accomplish that using `sprintf`?

Comment: There is no reason for `char* const arr`. Replace by char*.

Comment: To everyone, I am parsing strings into integers and was advised atoi() is the best-performing function (in terms of performance) for this.

Comment: @PavelRadzivilovsky I would rather use more const, than less const?

Comment: @user997112 `atoi` will not report an error if the conversion fails. If you have a C++11 compiler, use [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) instead

Comment: @user997112 Good general idea, but here const is really useless and even doesn't look good. It is not relevant beyond local scope. This is also why atoi signature is the way it is.

Comment: @Praetorian Jesus does not always properly remember the exact function of C++ functions. Also, I'm not Jesus, I'm an integer representation of Jesus, plus one! Silly Jesus ;)

Comment: @user997112 Before I post an answer, i need to know, does this file just contain a slew of character *digits* ONLY ('0'..'9') and you want the integer value of each *digit*? or is the file loaded with whitespace-separated integers (1234 2345 5434 etc..) and you want the integers sucked out into some array?

Comment: @WhozCraig it contains spaces, digits and end of line characters (and EOF)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I question your use of `const` in...

```
char* const arr = static_cast<char *>(file.get_address());
```

In this case, the `const` applies to the pointer, not to what it points at.  So, via your `arr` pointer, you could do this...

```
arr[0] = 'a';
```

...which I think is not what you're trying to protect against.  Instead, I think what you really want is:

```
const char* arr = static_cast<const char *>(file.get_address());
```

...which resolves what your question was posted about.  In this way, you have a pointer that points to characters that can't be changed (at least not directly through that pointer).

Then, in your loop, you're calling atoi() on each character of the whole file, which I doubt is what you really want to do.  Are you expecting a whole bunch of single-digit decimal (base 10) numbers, with no separators?  That's the only use case for looping the way you are.  For the sake of argument, let's suppose that's what you really want.  OK, then, where do you want the results to go?  You're not assigning the returned value of atoi() to anything.  You're converting the single-digit (presumably ASCII) numbers from text into numeric form, but throwing away the results.

But I think that's probably not what you really want anyway.

Let's rewrite your code so that it will convert the file's first textual value (assuming it's not preceded by garbage) into an integer, and then print it.  As in your example, we'll assume the file is already read into some object named `file` and that we can get its data buffer by calling `file.get_address()`.  Here's what you'd want:

```
const char* arr = static_cast<const char *>(file.get_address());

int firstNumericValue = atoi(arr);

std::cout << "firstNumericValue = " << firstNumericValue << "\n";
```

...and that's all, no looping required!  If you want to read in multiple values from the file, of course you could use looping, but you'll want to look into more advanced functions, such as `sscanf()` or `strtol()`.  If you use strtol(), its second argument lets you get a pointer to the next place to begin converting for any subsequent calls.  But examples for these abound, and you can research them yourself.

Comment: I'm worried sscanf() and such functions contain hidden memory copying, I want this to be as lean as possible (hence the loop etc).

Comment: @user997112 - If you're that concerned about overhead, sure, by all means, write your own conversion functions.  Most concerns about such things are unfounded.  I'm curious as to what your application is that you can't simply use the platform's tools for doing common conversions, and even if you implement your own I doubt that any performance improvement you could get would justify the expense of your time in writing & debugging it.

Comment: @user997112 - In any case, I strongly suggest that you first get your program working with standard tools.  If its performance is not as you require, then look into optimizations at that point.  In most cases, it's high-level algorithmic decisions that make the real performance impacts, not tiny differences in low-level operations like this.  But there are exceptions, especially if low-level operations like this are doing a ton of processing.

Comment: @WhozCraig - I think it was something like "Premature optimization is the root of all the feeble" or something like that? :)  I definitely agree... with the caveat that up-front optimization of program structure/design is much more important and meaningful than premature optimization of low-level implementation.  It really stinks to find out after a whole system is implemented that the whole system is hopelessly and fundamentally locked into n^2 performance due to an unfortunate early decision about a key system API.

Comment: ...Unfortunately it's not always obvious how an API can dictate performance characteristics like that, and often the naive "most logical" API gives exactly that (inherent n^2 performance, for example), when a seemingly "strange" interface enables the user to have n or n*log n performance.

Answer (score 2):

```
atoi(&(arr[i]));
```

will do the trick.

The `&` operator gives you a pointer to the char and the extra parentheses ensure that you are getting a pointer to the `i`-th element.

atoi doesn't care about the const on the array declaration, so it isn't relevant here.

Comment: or skip the & and the [] entirely and just use `atoi(arr+i)`

Comment: @WhozCraig - I'm betting neither `atoi(&(arr[i]));` nor `atoi(arr+i);` will "do the trick", unless the OP's goal is to get the remainders of each textual numeric value in the file divided by successively smaller powers-of-10, a goal for which both of these are well suited.

Comment: this wasn't really good for me because it didnt return the character, it returned a series of characters from the file. I just wanted to grab character by character

Comment: @phonetagger This wasn't my answer (note the author). I agree with you, and figured that based on my comment up in the main text. I was merely commenting here that all the extraneous punctuation wasn't needed for what the answerer was trying to do.